# Communication using SSL in android

Tags: android, ssl, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have to send data to remote server from android app using SSL. Where do I get certificates? What is the whole process both at client-server end for verification in android?

Can anyone tell me how can we do this?

Bundles of thanks

--Sam

Comment: you can generate certs yourself. but if you want it universally accepted, you'll have to buy one from an ssl provider.

Comment: You *likely* only need a certificate installed on the server side. Typically clients reference certificates from cert authorities to validate that the certificate provided by the server is authentic. Clients presenting certs to servers is less common (but can be done if needed). You get a lot of this for free by using HTTPS and using an appropriate HTTP/HTTPS client library. I think most of the stuff in org.apache.http and android.net.http class libraries have what you need.  Good book (old, but useful): http://www.amazon.com/SSL-TLS-Essentials-Securing-Web/dp/0471383546

Answer (score 0):

[Start SSL](https://www.startssl.com/?app=39) offers free class 1 certs, and works as a trusted certificate authority. Else you can do a self sign but as mentioned above, it won't be universally trusted.

Comment: Thanks. But how I post data to server using SSL in android?